# Logging on Azure - do I still need NLog (or equivalent)

Tags: logging, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net Core 2.2 Web Api which I've been hosting on our dedicated server at our ISP. Today I tried hosting it on Azure App Service and I think it's fantastic. The one thing I noticed is that Azure App Service has built-in logging. Currently my app is using NLog for logging to a text file. Does this mean that I could actually stop using NLog altogether? I'm really only interested in logging exceptions - and Azure App Service's built-in logging appears to do that automatically, without me having to write any code. Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I could actually stop using NLog altogether?

Yes, you could use the built-in Azure log for `ILogger`.

> I'm really only interested in logging exceptions - and Azure App Service's built-in logging appears to do that automatically, without me having to write any code.

For Azure Log Stream, it will log error during your application running.

But, you still need to handle expcetion by yourself for friendly error handing to avoid throw unexpected result to client user.

Comment: Thanks Tao. Ok, so in summary, if I want basic error logging in my .Net Core Web API, as long as it's hosted on Azure App Service, and logging has been enabled, I don't need to do anything. I don't need to write any logging code. I don't need any logging frameworks such as NLog. It's all done automatically by Azure App Service.